# При попытке открыть com port выдается ошибка "Не удается найти указанный файл"

Tags: c++, qt, serial, com-порт

В чем может быть проблема? Ниже приведен кусок кода. Так же есть рабочий большой проект с использованием com порта, его тут выкладывать не буду, но суть в том, что на одном пк все работает исправно, на другом вылезает та же ошибка "Не удается найти указанный файл".

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    serial = new QSerialPort(this);
    ui->setupUi(this);

    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
            ui->comboBox->addItem(info.portName());

    fillPortsParameters();
}

void MainWindow::fillPortsParameters()
{
    ui->baudRateBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("9600"), QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    ui->baudRateBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("19200"), 
    QSerialPort::Baud19200);
    ui->baudRateBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("38400"), 
    QSerialPort::Baud38400);
    ui->baudRateBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("115200"), 
    QSerialPort::Baud115200);

    ui->dataBitsBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("5"), QSerialPort::Data5);
    ui->dataBitsBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("6"), QSerialPort::Data6);
    ui->dataBitsBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("7"), QSerialPort::Data7);
    ui->dataBitsBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("8"), QSerialPort::Data8);
    ui->dataBitsBox->setCurrentIndex(3);

    ui->parityBox->addItem(tr("None"), QSerialPort::NoParity);
    ui->parityBox->addItem(tr("Even"), QSerialPort::EvenParity);
    ui->parityBox->addItem(tr("Odd"), QSerialPort::OddParity);
    ui->parityBox->addItem(tr("Mark"), QSerialPort::MarkParity);
    ui->parityBox->addItem(tr("Space"), QSerialPort::SpaceParity);

    ui->stopBitsBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("1"), QSerialPort::OneStop);
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    ui->stopBitsBox->addItem(tr("1.5"), QSerialPort::OneAndHalfStop);
#endif
    ui->stopBitsBox->addItem(QStringLiteral("2"), QSerialPort::TwoStop);

    ui->flowControlBox->addItem(tr("None"), QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    ui->flowControlBox->addItem(tr("RTS/CTS"), 
    QSerialPort::HardwareControl);
    ui->flowControlBox->addItem(tr("XON/XOFF"), 
    QSerialPort::SoftwareControl);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int current_port;
    current_port = ui->comboBox->currentIndex();
    //qDebug() <<  serial.currentReadChannel();
    serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    serial->setPortName("COM1");
    if(serial->isOpen())
        qDebug() << "1";

    if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
         QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Message"), tr("Open."));
         ui->pushButton_3->setEnabled(true);
         ui->pushButton_2->setEnabled(false);
    } else
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), serial->errorString());
    }

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    if(serial->isOpen())
        serial->close();

    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Message"), tr("Close."));
    ui->pushButton_3->setEnabled(false);
    ui->pushButton_2->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Не на всех компьютерах есть порт COM1

Comment: Подключаю к ПК преобразователь USB/UART, он распознается виндой как COM1

Comment: Всегда? При подключении к разным гнездам USB номер порта может меняться.

Comment: Да я подключаю к одному и тому же USB порту) и код не работает, в этом и проблема...

Comment: Другие программы (какой-нибудь терминал) при этом с портом работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос разрешился. Дело было в неправильных драйверах на мой преобразователь USB/UART. Как оказалось, необходимо поставить более старую версию драйверов, если стоит windows 8 и выше. MBo, спасибо за участие, всего вам доброго.